# PowerShell Auto assign IP

Tags: powershell

A computer is sent to a random location and gets a random IP address, but my task is set a correct IP address ended on .105, X.X.X.105.

My problem is to get the only IP address and edit it to the valid. Example Computer get 10.10.10.132 and I want to change it to 10.10.10.105
I don't know how to edit the IP address. I thinking about Split("."" ")

All computers are W10 and in a domain. I chose to make a script (as a scheduled task) that runs after turn on the computer and assign the IP address. Default Gateway is always X.X.X.254.

```
#check IP and get IP
$ipDefault = (Get-NetIPAddress -InterfaceAlias "Ethernet").IPAddress

#Here should be code to Get first 24 prefix length of network with the last dote

$IPComputer = "$ip + '105'"
$Gateway = "$ip + '254'"

#assigning an IP address
New-NetIPAddress –InterfaceAlias “Ethernet” –IPv4Address $IPComputer –PrefixLength 24 -DefaultGateway $Gateway
Set-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceAlias “Ethernet” -ServerAddresses 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4
```

I know I can put manually IP address, but I want to make the fully automatic script.

Comment: is `$ipDefault` a `[string]` or an `[ipaddress]`? if the 2nd, then you will need to use the `.IPAddressToString()` method to give you a string that you can work with. once you have that, use `$IP.Split('.')` to give you the four octets & you can replace the last one with your desired new 4th octet.

Comment: I'd guess that `$ipDefault` is an array of strings `<IPv6>,<IPv4>` (or `<IPv4>,<IPv6>`?) Narrow  to _IPv4_ string using `-AddressFamily IPv4` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [LastIndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.lastindexof?view=netframework-4.8) and [Substring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.8). This will split the string by the last occurrence of '.'.

You also need to ensure that you are only returning IPv4 addresses.

```bsh
$ipDefault = (Get-NetIPAddress -InterfaceAlias "Ethernet" -AddressFamily IPv4).IPAddress
$threeOctets = $ipDefault.Substring(0,$ipDefault.LastIndexOf('.'))
$newIP = $threeOctets + ".105"
```